# How to configure a website to understand specific/ user-dependent url paths?

Tags: url

what should I do if i want process dynamical requests to my website depending on the path-part of the url?

For example:
1. the visitor is accessing the following url:  translate.xyz/car/to/german
2. my webserver/ script/ whatever should understand that it has to translate "car" to German.

What do I need for that?

Thank you

Comment: I think this depends on your webserver. You need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the server handle those requests. Try out Flask for python, it'll let you do what you want to do and it is very beginner friendly.

Do a `pip install flask` and you're good to go! (If you do not have pip, it's pretty easy to get that as well. Search around and install off!)

Here's a teeny-tiny Flask-based-code for a head-start! :D

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/<word>/to/<lang>')
def hello_world(word, lang):
    return 'I am going to convert '+word+' to '+lang+'!'

app.run()
```

Yes. This is *all*!

And for the second part of the question, it's not fair on my part to answer. You need to look for a way to translate it! (psst, search for an api if you're entirely clueless)

Comment: Great ! Thank you for the info with Flask !

Comment: If your query is solved, mark so by selecting this as a solution... :D